# jQuery get input array key value of a previous row

Tags: jquery

I have this table in my view and i can add a new row in that table:

```
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r1">
    <td><input name="item[0][]" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input name="quantity[0][]" type="number"/></td>
    <td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

.jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(){
    var row = parseInt($('#t1 tr:last-child').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10) + 1;
        $('#t1').append('<tr id="r'+row+'"><td><input name="item[][]" type="text"/></td><td><input name="quantity[][]" type="number"/></td><td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
        var row = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);

    if (row > 1) {
            $('#r'+row).remove();
        $('#t1 tr:gt(0)').attr('id',function(i,o){
           return "r"+ (i+1);
        });
        }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sdtd3kLf/1/)

but when i add a new row i want to get the previous row first key [this_one] [ ]

```
<td><input name="item[this_one][]" type="text"/></td>
```

I hope You understand what i mean.

So how to get the value inside the first brackets/first key?

#### update

so when adding a new row i need that variable something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(){
    var row = parseInt($('#t1 tr:last-child').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10) + 1;
    var first_key = ?????

        $('#t1').append('<tr id="r'+row+'"><td><input name="item['+first_key+'][]" type="text"/></td><td><input name="quantity['+first_key+'][]" type="number"/></td><td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how I added `['+(row - 1)+']` as you where already calculating the `row` to update the `id`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(){
  var row = parseInt($('#t1 tr:last-child').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10) + 1;
  $('#t1').append('<tr id="r'+row+'"><td><input name="item['+(row - 1)+'][]" type="text"/></td><td><input name="quantity['+(row - 1)+'][]" type="number"/></td><td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function(){
  var row = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);

  if (row > 1) {
      $('#r'+row).remove();
      $('#t1 tr:gt(0)').attr('id',function(i,o){
         return "r"+ (i+1);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
<tr>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">
  <td><input name="item[0][]" type="text"/></td>
  <td><input name="quantity[0][]" type="number"/></td>
  <td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

**Update after chat discussion**
So the OP needed to get the value "this_one" as he actually explained in the question. [So this fiddle was the solution he was looking for](https://jsfiddle.net/sdtd3kLf/7/)

Comment: yes this is good for my create form, but when i edit the model that first key is actually the id and it will not be the same as row....so this will work only for creating, what about edit form....when there are already multiple rows, then i need somehow to get that first index key value so the new added row will go inside the same array

Comment: @lewis4u I might not really understand what you mean. But hasn't the row always got the number of `id - 1` cause it is like 0 indexed ?

Comment: no, when i load the edit form then i have something like this `<td><input name="item[81][110]" type="text"/></td>`

Comment: and i want to get that number 81,  so when i add a new row in that table it will be like this `<td><input name="item[81][new]" type="text"/></td>`

Comment: Why so ever this would work: https://jsfiddle.net/sdtd3kLf/4/ but hold on, I make you an example also with getting that number

Comment: @lewis4u so you might looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sdtd3kLf/5/ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137160/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-caramba).

Answer (score 0):

How about this 
`var first_key = $('#t1 tr:last-child > td:first-child > input').attr("name");
    var startPosition = first_key.indexOf("[");
  var endPosition = first_key.indexOf("]");
  var subStringName = first_key.substring(startPosition+1,endPosition);`

Var substringName will hold the value you are looking for.
This can be further improved by use of a regex instead of startposition and endPosition. I am not so good at regex hence tried doing everything by javascript functions.

Comment: a little too complicated...you are creating 3 more variables....if i would go to look back that code i would be lost